# Difference between ReadOnlyCollection string[] in the context of collection

Tags: c#, collections, readonly

```
IList<string> strList = new string[] { "Apple", "Mango", "Orange" };

IList<string> lst = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(new[]{"Google",
"MSN","Yahoo"});
```

In both cases i can not use ***"Add()"*** method for adding new items.then almost both 
declarations are same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the first, `strList[2] = "Pear";` will work... not with the second. Arrays are always mutable in that you can re-assign by index, even if you can't add/remove. A read-only-collection is just that: read-only.

Answer (score 3):

The items in `strList` can be changed (not added or removed, but changed).

Answer (score 2):

In the first declaration, you can still use the following:

```
strList[0] = "Not a fruit";
```

`ReadOnlyCollection<T>` wraps any `IList<T>` in a lightweight object. It passes all calls that wouldn't change the collection on to the wrapped object (get `Count`, get `Item[]`, `GetEnumerator`), but throws an exception for all calls that would change the collection (`Add`, `Remove`, `Clear`, set `Item[]`).

Arrays are not resizable, but they are not readonly. The distinction is important to understand or you can introduce some serious security issues, for an example see [Path.InvalidPathChars Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.invalidpathchars.aspx).